# Pandas groupby custom nlargest

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

When trying to solve my own question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69627654/converting-pseudo-algorithm-to-python-pandas-code) I came up with an interesting problem. Consider I have this dataframe

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)

df= pd.DataFrame(dict(group = np.random.choice(["a", "b", "c", "d"], 
                                                size = 100),
                       values = np.random.randint(0, 100, 
                                                size = 100)
                      )
                 )
```

I want to select top values per each group, but I want to select the values according to some range. Let's say, top `x` to `y` values per each group. If any group has less than `x` values in it, give `top(min((y-x), x))` values for that group.

In general, I am looking for a custom made alternative function which could be used with `groupby` objects to select not top `n` values, but instead top `x to y` range of values.

EDIT: [`nlargest()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nlargest.html) is a special case of the solution to my problem where `x = 1` and `y = n`

Any further help, or guidance will be appreciated

Adding an example with this `df` and this `top(3, 6)`. For every group output the values from top 3rd until top 6th values:

```py
group   value
a   190
b   166
a   163
a   106
b   86
a   77
b   70
b   69
c   67
b   54
b   52
a   50
c   24
a   20
a   11
```

As group c has just two members, it will output top(3)

```
group   value
a   106
a   77
a   50
b   69
b   54
b   52
c   67
c   24
```

Comment: can you give examples of expected output? it's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: provided example in the edited post, thank you

Answer (score 0):

there are other means of doing this and depending on how large your dataframe is, you may want to search `groupby slice` or something similar. You may also need to check my conditions are correct (<, <=, etc)

```
x=3
y=6
# this gets the groups which don't meet the x minimum
df1 = df[df.groupby('group')['value'].transform('count')<x]

# this df takes those groups meeting the minimum and then shifts by x-1; does some cleanup and chooses nlargest
df2 = df[df.groupby('group')['value'].transform('count')>=x].copy()
df2['shifted'] = df2.groupby('group').shift(periods=-(x-1))
df2.drop('value', axis=1, inplace=True)
df2 = df2.groupby('group')['shifted'].nlargest(y-x).reset_index().rename(columns={'shifted':'value'}).drop('level_1', axis=1)

# putting it all together
df_final = pd.concat([df1, df2])
df_final

   group  value
8      c   67.0
12     c   24.0
0      a  106.0
1      a   77.0
2      a   50.0
3      b   70.0
4      b   69.0
5      b   54.0
```